# Perpendicular Bisector loci

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find and plot the Cartesian equation of the loci of Z of the below equation.

$|{j-2z \over4z-3}|={1\over2}$

Am I correct in identifying this equation as a Perpendicular Bisector?

I've got a page of hand written working, but my answer is:

$y+1.5x+0.3125=0$

OK so I tried to do this:

$|{j-2z \over{1\over2}}|=|4z-3|$

Which I'm guessing you can't do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \left| \frac{j-2z}{4z-3} \right| &= \frac{1}{2} \\
  \left| \frac{j-2(x+yj)}{4(x+yj)-3} \right| &= \frac{1}{2} \\ 
  \left| \frac{2x+(1-2y)j}{(4x-3)+4yj} \right| &= \frac{1}{2} \\
  \frac{\sqrt{(2x)^{2}+(1-2y)^{2}}}
       {\sqrt{(4x-3)^{2}+16y^{2}}} &= \frac{1}{2} \\
  4[(2x)^{2}+(1-2y)^{2}] &=
  [(4x-3)^{2}+16y^{2}] \\
  4(4x^{2}+4y^{2}-4y+1) &= 16x^{2}+16y^{2}-24x+9 \\
  -16y+4 &= -24x+9 \\
  24x-16y-5 &= 0 \\
\end{align*}